# Embedding MapInfo MapXtreme Map to Web

Tags: mapinfo, web, embeddable-web-maps, mapxtreme

I have been stuck with this problem for days.

Some other department in my company created a map using MapInfo/MapXtreme. They have published a Tile Map Service. The Tile Map Service accepts SOAP requests and returns an XML that contains base64string of a tile image based on the parameter given (TileX, TileY and (zoom) level).

How do I embed a web map viewer (like google maps) using this service?

Comment: I have tried calling the services and notice that given a TileX, TileY, and (zoom) level value, it returns a tile image. I assume there are already some kind of library to be able to render map on web using this kind of service? @lynxlynxlynx

Comment: Plenty, for example leaflet.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the guidance! I tried leaflet, it seems to be working for now, except for one thing, the coordinates are off by a huge amount. The lat is off by 64, the lng is off by 200~, any idea? @lynxlynxlynx

Comment: This is a separate question, so please post it as such. The topical experts (=not me) will be more likely to see it then.